# Why do I get a 404 error when I send a request to the next server?

Tags: next.js, http-status-code-404, nodemailer

When sending a request to the Sendmail.ts api, an error occurs [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (sendMail, line 0)

I wrote the api myself using nodemailer in next. And I also attached a fetch that should send a request. I tried all possible locations of the api folder in the project, and the app and src and global directories do not help

```
const handleSubmitForm = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Отправка данных на сервер
    const response = await fetch('/api/sendMail', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            senderEmail: formInputs.email,
            name: formInputs.name,
            message: formInputs.message,
            floortype: selectedFloor,
            postcode: formInputs.postcode,
            location: formInputs.location,
        }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        // Обработка успешной отправки
        console.log('Письмо успешно отправлено!');
    } else {
        // Обработка ошибки отправки
        console.error('Ошибка при отправке письма');
    }
}
```

```
onst transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 service: 'gmail',
 auth: {
     user: 'romanenkofloors@gmail.com',
     pass: '**********',
 }
});


export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
         const { senderEmail, name, message, floortype, postcode, location }: MailData = req.body;

    // Cодержание письма
    const mailOptions = {
        from: senderEmail,
        to: 'romanenkofloors@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Новый запрос от посетителя',
        text: `Имя: ${name}\nEmail: ${senderEmail}\nПочтовый индекс: ${postcode}\nГород: ${location}\nТип желаемого покрытия: ${floortype}\nВопрос: ${message}`,
    };

    try {
        await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
        res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Ошибка при отправке письма' });
    }
} else {
    res.status(405).end();
}
}
```

Comment: are you using app router or pages dir ? and where your api file is located in nextjs ?

Comment: @Inam I use App Router, and I placed the api file in the app directory, in src and in the global one. In all 3 cases, when following the link to this api, it gave a 404 error

Comment: your api file should be in src/api/sendmail/route.ts. api file should not be sendmail.ts, it should be route.ts and inside sendmail directory

Comment: @Inam Thank you very much, it helped, now there is an error that Google does not allow authorization and I get error 500, I will look into it further